# Send input type file without using submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have the form to attach the document and the js to send the data to php as follows:

```js
function update_estado()
{   
  var dadosajax = {
        'Fornecedor' : $("#Fornecedor3").val(),
        'arquivo': $("#arquivo").val(),
  }
  
  $.ajax({
      url: 'pedencom.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
          data: dadosajax,
      error: function(){
        $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
          swal("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
      },
      success: function(result2)
       {
         $('.limp9')[0].reset();    
         
       }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp9" id="forarq" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <div class="form-group col-md-3">  
    <select class="form-control1 spoiler4" name="Fornecedor" id="Fornecedor3" required>
     <option value="xxxxxx@hotmail.com">xxxxxx@hotmail.com</option>                     </select>
    <label class="label1" for="Fornecedor3">Email Fornecedor</label>        
 </div>
 <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top: -1%;">
    <span class="btn fileinput-button" style="color: black;">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: black;"></i>
     <span style="color: black;">Add Arquivo...</span>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" style="height: 62%;" id="arquivo" name="arquivo">
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="h4 mb-4" style="float:right; line-height: 2;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-default ripple-effect" onclick="update_estado()">Gravar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
 </div>
</form>
```

The variable with the email sends, but the input type file variable is empty.

I want to send both variables without submitting by clicking the save button.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
function update_estado()
{   
// here is my code
 var pedpront = [];
 $.each($("input[name='updorc1[]']:checked"), function(){ pedpront.push($(this).val()); });
  let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#forarq"))})  
// get the values here and insert in key value pair down below
formData.append("pedprontData",pedpront)
  $.ajax({
      url: 'pedencom.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
          data:,formData
      error: function(){
        $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
          swal("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
      },
      success: function(result2)
       {
         $('.limp9')[0].reset();    
         
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: When doing this way I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: can you paste the whole error stack

Comment: remove enctype and method attributes from <form> tag and check

Comment: The problem is that through this ajax I send the variables of this form and another variable that I'm going to get in the table where I selected the line I want to open and if I do as I said I won't send the variable from the table.

Comment: try the new code hope this will fix the issue

Comment: So I'm doing it this way: `var pedpront = []; $.each($("input[name='updorc1[]']:checked"), function(){ pedpront.push($(this).val()); }); let data = new FormData($("#forarq")[0]); var dadosajax = { 'Id[]' : pedpront } data: {data:data, dadosajax:dadosajax},`

Comment: I can't access the chat

Comment: you want to access the data from the table element and append to this form data is that you  want ??

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: ive updated the code accordingly let me know if have any query

Comment: Here it would look like this since it's the name of my array? `formData.append("key",pedpront)`.  
my table variable `var pedpront = []; $.each($("input[name='updorc1[]']:checked"), function(){ pedpront.push($(this).val()); });`

Comment: It gives this error if you put it like this formData.append("key",pedpront): `Failed to construct 'FormData': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function`.

Comment: sorry forgot to add new keyword check now it will work

Comment: Keep giving this error `Failed to construct 'FormData': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function and keep in mind that reader.result is file content string
base64encoded which means you need to decode it on server-side to get original content and save it.

```
function update_estado()
{ 
    var file = $('#arquivo')[0].files[0];
    var filename = file.name;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload=function() {
    var dadosajax = {
        'Fornecedor' : $("#Fornecedor3").val(),
        'arquivo': reader.result,
    }
  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pedencom.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
            swal("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
        },
        success: function(result2)
        {
            $('.limp9')[0].reset();     
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: And since I decode server-side to get the original content, I don't need to save

Comment: Then, this piece of javascript code will be enough, hope it will work

Comment: I don't need to save, I want to attach the pdf or email with phpmailer. Is it enough with this javascript?

Comment: This way, only with javascript, do not attach the pdf to the email sending with phphmailer